# Add Storyboard as subview in UIViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, storyboard-reference

I am creating a reusable view for which I have created a separate `Storyboard`. This reusable view will be added in different `UIViewController` is `Main.StoryBoard`. For this I followed storyboard reference. But I am not sure how to add `Storyboard` as a **subview** inside a `UIViewController` having some definite frame.
Please let me know if you want to have a screenshot as to how I am designing the screen.

Answer (score 2):

first you need to get the reference of the storyboard from the different storyboard.

```
UIViewController *viewControllerToAdd =
    [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil]instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewForPopover"];
```

//Instead of MainStoryboard you write the name of the Storyboard which you have created separately

the you write these lines

```
[self addChildViewController:viewControllerToAdd];
[self.view addSubview:viewControllerToAdd.view];
[viewControllerToAdd didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

This much should probably do, i havent tried it yet

Answer (score 0):

make reusable `UIViewController` and then `addChildViewController` wherever you want. Below i made `RemarksViewController` which i used in many views of `UIViewController`

```
    RemarksViewController *vC=[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"yourStoryboardName" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"showRemarks"];
    [self addChildViewController:vC];
    vC.view.bounds=self.view.bounds;
    [self.view addSubview:vC.view];
    [vC didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```